# More than 4 morphnormals to a materials in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
function loadhairmat(path)
{
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(  { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( path )} );
return material;
}
```

How to apply more than 4 normal map to a material.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're wanting to do, you might want to look at re-phrasing or clarifying where you are struggling to update things (e.g. it could be that you just want the JSON notation for an array or a new function taking in an array of paths)

Answer (score 0):

```
var materials = [
       new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: ..)}),
       new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: ..)}),
       new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: ..)}),
       new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: ..)}),
       new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: ..)})
       //..
    ];

var obj= new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 562, 562, 562, 1, 1, 1 ),
    new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
scene.add( obj );
```